# How to resolve this error: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, netbeans, server

I try to open my project in Java Web using Netbeans but i dont know how to resolve this.

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
**type** Exception report

**message** Internal Server Error

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "eCommerce" does not exist

**root cause**

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "eCommerce" does not exist

**note** The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0 logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "eCommerce" does not exist

This is the cause of the exception. Your application is trying to access a PostgreSQL database 'eCommerce' which doesn't seem to exist. You will have to create the database 'eCommerce', if you have access to the database server and the privileges to do so.

Comment: This is not an answer since the OP obviously understands the cause of the exception. They are asking _"how to resolve this"_. And the error message doesn't necessarily mean that the OP will _"have to create the database 'eCommerce'"_ either.

Comment: Hmm, well, in the end, I think it helped the user, since the answer is now accepted. I agree with you @skomisa that it didn't necessarily mean that the database has to be created. What I actually meant by that that the database has to exist for the application to be able to connect to it, but I agree I should have been more precise in my answer. I also couldn't ask for more clarification by placing comments, because I lacked the 50 reputation points back then, which are required to place comments...

Comment: OK, fair enough, and I can't argue with an accepted answer! Have another upvote.